# Why does accessing columns of a pandas dataframe with .loc[] produce duplicate rows?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, duplicates

Why is `.loc[]` producing duplicate rows in my DataFrame? I'm trying to select a few columns from m3, a DataFrame with 47 columns,to create a new DataFrame called output.

The problem: after accessing m3's columns with `.loc[]`, output has way more duplicates than m3 started with. Where could these duplicates have come from? I haven't found anything online about `.loc[]` duplicating rows. The output DataFrame is declared on the line that reads `output = m3.loc[...]`, by the way.

The Code:

```
print("ARE THERE DUPLICATES in m3? ")
print(m3.duplicated().loc[lambda x: x==True])

output = m3.loc[:,["PLC_name", "line", "track", "notes", "final_source", 
"s_name", "s_line", "s_track", "loc", "alt_loc", "suffix", "alt_match_name"]]

print("ARE THERE DUPLICATES in output? ")
print(output.duplicated().loc[lambda x: x==True].size, "duplicates")
```

The Terminal Output:

```
ARE THERE DUPLICATES in m3? 
5241    True
5242    True
5243    True
5355    True
5356    True
5357    True
dtype: bool
ARE THERE DUPLICATES in output? 
1838 duplicates
```

Of course, I could easily fix the problem by calling `.drop_duplicates(keep="first")`, but I'm more interesting in learning why `.loc[]` displays this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`output` filters for **selected columns** from `m3`. When you call `duplicated` on `m3`, *all* columns from the original dataframe are considered. When you call `duplicated` on `output`, only a *subset* of those columns is considered.

Therefore, you can have duplicates in `output` even when there are no duplicates in `m3`.

Here's a minimal and reproducible example of what you're seeing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[3, 8, 9], [4, 8, 9]])
print(df.duplicated().sum(), 'duplicates')
# 0 duplicates

df_filtered = df.loc[:, [1, 2]]
print(df_filtered.duplicated().sum(), 'duplicates')
# 1 duplicates
```

Comment: Thanks @jpp! I was looking at this for a solid hour and now I'm having a real "duh" moment. Like why didn't I see it sooner! Anyhow, I upvoted your answer too, I suppose it'll show when I have more reputation.